# how to get startDate from timerange javascript/angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two range selectors in my angularjs view and I'm trying to get startDate and endDate to perform queries to my BD on the controller.

when I do on browser

```
document.getElementsByName("customrange")[0]
```

I get

```
<input type="text" name="customrange" ng-model="parent.customrange" ng-change="applyOptions()" class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ui-jq="daterangepicker" ui-options="{format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',startDate: '&quot;2017-07-17T13:14:22.986Z&quot;',endDate: '&quot;2017-07-17T14:30:20.563Z&quot;', maxDate:'&quot;2017-07-17T14:30:20.563Z&quot;'}" style="">
```

How can I get startDate and endDate with javascript code?

Comment: Use data-tags or two way binding.

Comment: Dont understand, sorry

Comment: [See this example](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/twowaydatabinding/) and [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding). As to `data-tags`: [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and [Mozilla Developers Network's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). If you create a fiddle or a codepen, it might be easier to help you.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5QaSxPXkz9Ts0mzCY4RE?p=preview